# Реализовать Интерфейс механизма «умного» присвоения номеров элементам списка

Tags: java

Заранее прошу прощения за назойливость.

Но либо я что-то не понимаю, либо с условием задачи что-то не так!? 
Сразу говорю что мне надо правильно его(условие) понять. Реализацию сделаю сам.

Вот условие:

Реализовать Интерфейс механизма «умного» присвоения номеров элементам списка.

```
public interface IElementNumberAssigner {

/**
 * Метод выставляет номера {IElement#setupNumber(int)}
 * для элементов коллекции {elements}
 * в порядке следования элементов в коллекции.
 *
 * Изначально коллекция не содержит элементов, номера которых повторяются.
 *
 * При этом обеспечиваются слеюущие условия:
 *      метод работает только с существующими элементами (не создает новых),
 *      на протяжении всей работы метода обеспечивается уникальность номеров элементов:
 *      вызов {element.setNumber(i)} разрешен ⇔   ∀ e ∊ {elements} (e.number ≠ i),
 *      метод устойчив к передаче в него в качестве параметра {java.util.Collections#unmodifiableList(List)} и любой другой реализации immutable-list,
 *      метод должен работать за «приемлемое» время ({IElement#setupNumber(int)} - трудоемкая операция и пользоваться ей надо рационально)
 *
 * elements элементы, которым нужно выставить номера
 */

void assignNumbers(List<IElement> elements);
```

}

У меня вопрос: в чем подвох?

Разве нельзя просто пробежаться от начала до конца списка и присвоить каждому элементу номер по порядку? В чем сложность не пойму?

Answer (score 1):

Сложность в том, что у передаваемого списка элементы уже имеют номера. И в процессе работы метода нельзя допускать, чтобы номера у каких либо двух элементов совпали. Т.е. если передан список 5,4,3,2,1 нельзя просто начать перенумеровывать с первого элемента с единицы, иначе будет задвоение единиц.

Comment: _"Сложность в том, что у передаваемого списка элементы уже имеют номера"._ Откуда это? В первоначальном вопросе этого не видно.

Comment: Читайте внимательно
> вызов {element.setNumber(i)} разрешен ⇔   ∀ e ∊ {elements} (e.number ≠ i)

Comment: Да, на эти "загогулины" с множествами не обратил внимание.

Comment: Тогда не понятно, как такой набор элементов с номерами 5,4,3,2,1 вообще нумеровать в порядке следования элементов в коллекции? Ведь мне придется в любом случае верхнему элементу присваивать его номер следования т.е. 1 ?

Comment: Грубо говоря, чтобы первому элементу коллекции установить номер "1", мне надо проверить - нет ли такого номера у какого то ещё элемента в коллекции? И если окажется что есть - то временно заменить "найденную 1-цу" чем то другим?, затем уже присваивать первому элементу 1 ? Я правильно понимаю?

Comment: @Vard32 вы же сказали, что реализуете сами )) Вариантов много, вам самое главное нужно сохранить инвариант - все номера разные в любой момент времени.

Comment: @Vard32 Самое простое первый проход:`element.setNumber(-element.getNumber());` второй проход: `element.setNumber(i)`. В случае когда вызов `setNumber` слишком дорог (что двукратный вызов не приемлем), можно закешировать номера+индексы в хэшмэп и перенумеровывать, проверяя занят ли номер. если номер будет занят, придется устанавливать временные значения...

Answer (score 0):

> метод устойчив к передаче в него в качестве параметра `java.util.Collections#unmodifiableList(List)` и любой другой реализации immutable-list

проблема в том, что вашему методу может быть передана коллекция объектов, которую нельзя модифицировать, т.е. read-only. Вы не сможете записать номер в какое-либо поле объекта. Следовательно, номера объектов необходимо хранить отдельно от самих объектов и, возможно, иметь какую-то связь между номерами объектов и самими объектами, хотя про связь в вашем задании ничего нет. Но поскольку метод `assignNumbers` ничего не возвращает, непонятно что с этими номерами делать дальше и как вообще узнать что они присвоены объектам.

А там ещё ссылка на какой-то метод `IElement#setupNumber(int)`, надо как-то его использовать...

Comment: Да, дело в том, что там весьма четко прописаны правила реализации: интерфейс IElement обязывает реализовать методы: long getId();  int getNumber(); и void setupNumber(int number); Если с первыми двумя всё понятно, то последний совершенно точно присваивает номер int.

Comment: Да.. и ещё вот эта фраза: "метод работает только с существующими элементами (не создает новых)"

Comment: Тут-то как раз всё понятно. Нельзя создавать новых элементов в переданной методу коллекции для нумерации.

Comment: может быть [это](https://github.com/musius/JavaTask2) поможет?

Comment: Может. Но хочется понять смысл на уровне постановки задачи. В частности, если речь идет о порядке следования элементов в коллекции, то (как я понимаю) этот порядок мне надо будет так или иначе устанавливать. Мне ведь сортировать элементы нельзя!